# How to color (a different color) duplicated items in blender 2.91?

Tags: color

[image]

I know in the previous versions we there is a number 2 (at the red arrow shown in the picture) so that we can color the duplicated object another color. But how to do it in blender 2.91? I tried pressing the button shown in the picture but the duplicated object's color is still linked to the original object.

Comment: Hello :). Are these linked duplicates? If so, you need to link the Material to Object, not Mesh data (it's the switch to the right)

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the Materials to Object, so they're no longer synced.
Mesh Data are synced, so any change affects all of them.

It's the *Object/Data switch* in Material tab.

[image]